# How do properly use CSS Image sprites?

Tags: html, css, sprite

I have a website i am trying to speed up and I am doing small things here and there. One of the things I would like to do but have not ever learned how to do is utilize image sprites.

Example here: http://flag-sprites.com/

Going to use the following code as an example:

```
<ul>
<li><div class"flag flag-zw"></div> Country Name</li>
<li><div class"flag flag-zw"></div> Country Name</li>
<li><div class"flag flag-zw"></div> Country Name</li>
<li><div class"flag flag-zw"></div> Country Name</li>
</ul>
```

I am trying to get the flags to show up beside the country name. This sprite comes pre positioned so that all I have to do is place the image and call the class. Any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks!

Comment: http://css-tricks.com/css-sprites/

Comment: Step 1. Replace the periods with spaces in your class attribute. Step 2. Read the article that @Curt linked to.

Comment: Another great tool that goes hand in hand with sprite sheets is [Sprite Cow](http://www.spritecow.com/).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a <kbd>**[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/mdesdev/4h8e7/)**</kbd>

```
<ul>
  <li><span class="flag flag-ad"></span>Country Name</li>
  <li><span class="flag flag-ae"></span>Country Name</li>
  <li><span class="flag flag-af"></span>Country Name</li>
  <li><span class="flag flag-ag"></span>Country Name</li>
</ul>


.flag {
  background: url(http://s22.postimg.org/u0nt2h8qp/flags.png) no-repeat;
  display: inline-block;
  margin-right: 10px;
  width: 16px;
  height: 11px;
}
.flag.flag-ad { background-position: -16px 0 }
.flag.flag-ae { background-position: -32px 0 }
.flag.flag-af { background-position: -48px 0 }
.flag.flag-ag { background-position: -64px 0 }
```

[image: Fiddle result]

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the code examples already posted will get you what you need. But, in addition to that I would like to suggest the tool [Sprite Cow](http://www.spritecow.com).  This tool makes finding css position values very easy.

Comment: Very nice! Thanks for your post! Now that I know how to use the sprites this tool makes it much easier. =)

Answer (score 0):

Here you go:

I would make the flags **span** but div is fine too:

```
<li><span class="flag flag-aw"></span> Aruba</li>
```

CSS

```
.flag {width: 16px; height: 11px; background: url("http://static.flag-sprites.com/i/flags.png") no-repeat 0 0; margin-right: .3em; display: inline-block;}

.flag-aw {background-position: -224px 0;}
```

Example:

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/Riskbreaker/q9CLh/1/)

..Theres no need to bother with "blank.gif" . If you have Phtoshop or GIMP(free) you can get the proper dimensions where the images are positioned.